# integral = zero

Tags: integration, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function in $[a,b]$

For every continuous function $g(x)$ :
$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cdot g(x)\;\mathrm dx=0$

We need to prove that $f(x)=0$.

I thought about proving by contradiction but it's not working...
Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you considered defining $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ and a partition of $[a,b]$?.

Comment: No they told me that we can use g=f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $g = f$. This gives $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx=0$. Since $f^2$ is continue and positive everywhere, $f^2 = 0_{[a,b]}$ and $f = 0_{[a,b]}$.

**Detailed proof of the latter** : $f$ is continue everywhere, so is $f^2$. Let's suppose that $\exists y \in ]a,b[, f(y)^2 = c > 0$.

Then since $f^2$ is continue, $\exists \nu > 0, \forall x \in [y, y+\nu], |f(y)^2-f(x)^2| < c/2$.

So  $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx \geq \int_{y}^{y+\nu}f(x)^2dx \geq \nu*c/2 > 0$, which is a contradiction.

So $\forall x \in [a,b], f(x)^2 = 0$, so $\forall x \in [a,b], f(x) = 0$. So $f = 0_{[a,b]}$.

Comment: it works if we choose g(x)=f(x) but who said g(x)=f(x) ?
maybe not

Comment: I have corrected some typos in my answer. I don't get your question though. The statement is "for every continuous function g". I have just chosen one.

Comment: 100% now I understand 
yes we can just choose a particular g=f Thank you for the detailed answer